# Find the top left point of shape after rotation

Tags: c#, coordinates

I have a rectangle shape called the Base(height=700px,width=300px) and I want to create a Cover shape that rotates in 45 deg( clockwise/anticlockwise) that can cover the Base.

[image]

Currently, I create the Cover shape with the width and height equal to the length of points b1 to c1 of the Base. Now I only want to know where should I put the point a2 of the Cover after the rotation so that it will look as the image above.

Comment: I'd say it looks good where you've put it ;)   Where is the C# code for this C# question?

Comment: If the covering shape is always going to be a square with 45 degrees of rotation, then you can find the points with simple geometric formulas. As the surrounding triangles are isosceles right ones, the distance of a2 from the left edge is `height/2` so you can find x of it as `a1.x - height / 2`. The y is also find in the same way and it is equal to `a1.y + height /2`